# Automated Scripts in MySQL taken a long time to execute

Tags: mysql, sql

When executing a MySQL script that returns data from 3 inner joined tables through the Interactive SQL application, I can get 1.02 million records to write to a text file in 35 minutes. That same query, when executed automatically using dbisqlc.exe takes approximately 6.2 hours to run and produce the same data file.

How can I go about speeding the automation up?

```
SELECT *
FROM dba.t_cust a, dba.v_customer c , dba.v_cust_name n
where a.acct_id = c.acct_id and     
      c.acct_id = n.acct_id
ORDER by upd_datetime desc
```

Comment: Add indexes. Take advantage of the `EXPLAIN` syntax. I have no idea what `dbisqlc.exe` is, but nothing here is about PHP.

Comment: It doesn't seem like there's enough info here to determine why it's slow.

Comment: *through the Interactive SQL application*...what is that? The MySQL workbench? Btw - it doesn't add to performance but does to readability, use [explicit joins and not implicit joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44917/explicit-vs-implicit-sql-joins) as you use. It the ANSI standard of 25 years!